# Is there any way to simplify deriving for structs with unused generic parameters?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to add some type safety to some structs to secure correct usage. For example, an ID is bound to the type of the entity it identifies.

```rust
pub trait MarkerEntity {
    
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct A;
impl MarkerEntity for A {}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct B;
impl MarkerEntity for B {}

use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct ID<T>
where T: MarkerEntity {
    value: u64,
    entity_type: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> ID<T>
where T: MarkerEntity {
    pub fn new(value: u64) -> Self {
        Self { value, entity_type: PhantomData } 
    }
}
```

To use such pattern I need to derive everything I would need on my marker structs to pass the bounds checks of the further `derive`s (or use [derivative](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/) crate).
Is there any way to simplify what I want in the current version of Rust?
I suppose that const generics would make it easier but, AFAIK, they won't land anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a much nicer way to do what you want. You could utilize macros to reduce some of boilerplate. If you have a lot of marker struct then at least you only have to define the derives for all markers in one place.

```rust
trait MarkerEntity {}

macro_rules! marker_entity {
    ($Name:ident) => {
    
        #[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
        pub struct $Name;

        impl MarkerEntity for $Name {}     

    }
}

marker_entity!(A);
marker_entity!(B);
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. I didn't think about rolling a helper macro. I don't have a lot, but it still would help to have all derives in one place.